# Is it possible to add local domain name like (serverabc.com )on local network

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system

I have the local webserver on ubuntu inside virtual machine.
Currently i access it via IP like

```
http://10.0.11.111
```

Is it possible i can DNS name for that ip which works only on local network like

```
http://companyserver.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. See `/etc/hosts/`, 
you want something like this:

```
10.0.11.111    companyserver.local
```

(don't use .com unless you have to, it's bad practice)